# Version number as a string getting truncated to single number

Tags: c, string, parsing

question in C

I am receiving a serial string which is 7.0.0*(crlf)

When I copy the string above into another string and strip out the characters I don't want, the string is 7.0.0  (I know it is copying all 5 characters due to debugging output in my copy loop).

when I printf("%s",myvalue)  it is returning literally 7, and not 7.0.0

I need to be able to keep the whole string intact so that myvalue shows/outputs 7.0.0, not 7.

How do I do this??

unsigned int ESPFWVERSION[10]   ;

```
   SendATandExpectResponse("AT+VERSIONINFO2", "OK");
   sprintf(ttlbuffer, "%s\r\n",RESPONSE_BUFFER);
   SendStringSerially(ttlbuffer);    
    int j=0;

    for (int i = 0; RESPONSE_BUFFER[i]!='*'; i++)
    {
           chR = RESPONSE_BUFFER[i] ;
             ESPFWVERSION[j] = chR;     
             j++;

   sprintf(ttlbuffer, "j=%i \r\n",j);
   SendStringSerially(ttlbuffer);           

    }
    
   // strcpy_s(ESPFWVERSION, j, RESPONSE_BUFFER);
    ESPFWVERSION[j+1] = '\0';        

   sprintf(ttlbuffer, "(%s)\r\n",ESPFWVERSION);
   SendStringSerially(ttlbuffer);
```

Output from:     sprintf(ttlbuffer, "%s\r\n",RESPONSE_BUFFER);
SendStringSerially(ttlbuffer);
is 7.0.0*crlf

Output from the last command is (7)crlf

Comment: If the debug information and the printed output don't match... you're either doing something wrong (probable)... or doing more than you say (probable)... or you have a bug in your implementation (highly improbable). *Pay attention to line 42 :-)*

Comment: How do you receive the string? And more importantly, how do you *strip* and *copy* the string? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: You need to post your actual code.

Comment: Thank you -I revised my post above

Comment: data is coming from an ESP32 to a PIC processor via serial interface.

Comment: `unsigned int ESPFWVERSION[10] ;` and `sprintf(ttlbuffer, "(%s)\r\n",ESPFWVERSION);` mismatch

Comment: Milton Augustine, Save time and enable all warnings to quickly catch such errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong variable type.

```
unsigned int ESPFWVERSION[10] ;
```

changed it to

```
unsigned char ESPFWVERSION[10] ;
```

and now it is fixed.